# "Expected 84 but got 2 pulses" error with DHT22 thermal sensor on raspberry pico

Tags: pi-pico, dht22

I followed this tutorial to setup DHT22 thermal sensor on a raspberry pico: https://peppe8o.com/dht11-humidity-and-temperature-sensor-with-raspberry-pi-pico-and-micropython/?unapproved=7929&moderation-hash=06e75605461fa63372815fc1bebd285f#comment-7929 which uses this class to drive the sensor: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ikornaselur/pico-libs/master/src/dht11/dht.py

But I'm getting the following error:

```
"Expected 84 but got 2 pulses"
```

which is defined in line 98 of the DHT class.

I'm running the sensor with the following code:

```
from machine import Pin
import utime as time
from DHT11 import DHT11, InvalidChecksum
dhtPIN = 15
dhtSensor = DHT11(Pin(dhtPIN, Pin.OUT, Pin.PULL_DOWN))

while True:
    print("Temp: {}°C".format(dhtSensor.temperature), \
          "| Hum: {0:.1%}".format(dhtSensor.humidity/100))
    time.sleep(2.1)
```

One thing, the pins in my pico are not soldered, but even if I push the pico down the error keeps coming.

Comment: please format the code

Comment: The github lib seems for PyBoard DHT11. Are you sure it works for Rpi Pico DHT22?

Comment: that could indeed be the problem! do I need to do small edit in the code or I should find another library at all?

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect a DHT22 loosely connected to a Pico to work.  You need secure soldered connections.

Comment: is that error what you would expect from unstable connections?